# How do I execute a specific code block for only the first iteration of a loop?

Tags: php

How do I execute a specific code block for `only` the first iteration of a loop?

[image: Schematic image]

Comment: perhaps you could make a function to be called within the first iteration

Comment: I don't see the need for two code blocks here.  After the sequence of statements in the first block completes, the sequence of statements in the second block will execute.  Then the loop will repeat.  Take out the `}{` in the middle and doesn't that achieve the desired effect?

Comment: @David, thank you David, I tried this approach but is not working. I'm trying to generate images in the first block and further process them in the second block, so if I remove `}{`, the second block does not execute.

Comment: @Apiah then perhaps you should show an example of your actual code instead of pseudo-code, so we can help with what's actually wrong

Comment: @Apiah: Why doesn't it execute?  If there's an error which stops code execution then you'd need to fix that error.  The overall structure of `foreach ($images as $image) { ... }` is going to execute everything in that block, unless an error stops the code.

Comment: @David, thanks for your time. I added the code in the question, the code generates the thumbnails, but does not echo the `$image_size` after each iteration.

Comment: @Apiah: Then you need to do some debugging.  Maybe step through in a debugger, or do a `var_dump` somewhere to determine the state of the values and make sure the value are what you expect them to be at runtime.  If the code is executing, then it's executing.  Look for errors in the logs, debug the code, etc.

Comment: @David, sure I'll follow your response, thanks again, cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're asking for sounds somewhat like [goto](http://www.php.net/goto), which in general isn't good practice, and won't *really* work for you.

**Suggestion #1**

Seeing as how it looks like you want the 2nd code block to execute every time the first one is iterated, is there any reason why you can't just put the 2nd code block within the first?

**Suggestion #2**

Put code block #2 in a function and call the function:

```
foreach ($images as $image) {
  someFunction();
}

function someFunction() {
  // do something
}
```

pass `someFunction()` variable(s) if you need to. Have it return a value and assign the returned value to a variable for your loop if you have to.

Answer (score 7):

Do you mean to ask, "How do I execute a specific code block for *only* the first iteration of a loop"?  With a standard `for` loop you can just check the counter, something like:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($images); i++) {
    if ($i == 0) {
        // do this once
    }
    // do this always
}
```

With a `foreach` loop you can introduce a flag value of some kind, for example:

```
$i = 0;
foreach ($images as $image) {
    if ($i++ == 0) {
        // do this once
    }
    // do this always
}
```

Or perhaps a boolean flag:

```
$firstIteration = true;
foreach ($images as $image) {
    if ($firstIteration == true) {
        // do this once
        $firstIteration = false;
    }
    // do this always
}
```

Of course, all of this begs the question of why this needs to be in the loop at all.  Consider something like this:

```
// do this once
foreach ($images as $image) {
    // do this always
}
```

If it should only be executed when the collection has elements, you can easily check for that:

```
if (count($images) > 1) {
    // do this once
}
foreach ($images as $image) {
    // do this always
}
```

Ultimately, loops are for invoking an action on every element in a collection.  If you want to invoke an action once for the entire collection, that action probably doesn't belong in a loop.